# How to overload operator [ ] in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, operators, overloading

I have some problems for overloading the `operator []` in C++ for a matrix.Let's say that in my `Class Matrix` I have a 2X2 `matrix m[2][2]`.What the code should look like if I want to call an element from the array `m[1][1]` instead of `object.m[1][1]` ? I guess the header should be something like `int operator[] (const int)` but I don't know how to build it...If someone can help me thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend sticking with `m(1, 1)`.

Comment: @chris, additional explanation for a beginner would be very welcome

Comment: @piotruś He's suggesting one of the classical solutions: overload `operator()( int i, int j )` to return a reference to a single element, then use `m( i, j )` rather than `m[i][j]`.  A lot of numeric experts seem to prefer this form anyway.

Comment: sure, I just suggest to write this explicitly after brief, rough recommendation

Comment: [Why you shouldn't](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/matrix-array-of-array.html).

Answer (score 5):

There are two solutions.  First, as @chris suggests, you can use
`operator()( int i, int j )`; a lot of mathematically oriented
people even prefer this.  Otherwise, `operator[]` has to return
a proxy; a type on which `[]` is also defined, to which the
second `[]` can be applied to return the correct results.  For
two dimensional structures, the simplest proxy is just a pointer
to the row, since `[]` is defined for pointers.  But it's often
preferable to return a full class type, in order to do error
checking.  Something like:

```
template <typename T>
Matrix2D
{
    int myRowCount;
    int myColumnCount;
    std::vector<T> myData;
public:
    T& getRef( int i, int j )
    {
        return myData[ i * myRowCount +  j ];
    }

    class Proxy
    {
        Matrix2D* myOwner;
        int myRowIndex;
    public:
        Proxy( Matrix2D* owner, int i )
            : myOwner( owner )
            , myRowIndex( i )
        {
        }

        T& operator[]( int j )
        {
            return myOwner->getRef( myRowIndex, j );
        }
    };

    Proxy operator[]( int i )
    {
        return Proxy( this, i );
    }
};
```

You'll probably want a const version of the Proxy as well, in
order to overload `[]` on const.

For the `()` version, just replace `getRef` with `operator()`
(literally), and drop the `Proxy` and the `operator[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much.I implemented "the" @chris solution and it works perfectly.I've never thought of using () instead of [].

Comment: @user3187893 Both solutions work well.  It's a question of user preference.  Here, we use the @chris solution as well, and the users seem quite happy with it; but in places where I've worked earlier, the proxy solution (and `m[i][j]`) was preferred.

Comment: Oh geez, I'm becoming popular. Thanks for drawing it out after I went away for a bit too long.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how operator [] can be implemented for a class that has a two-dimensional array
Try it and you will be satisfied.:)

You will need neither a proxy nor a compound operator function.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        int a[10][10];
        int ( & operator []( int n ) )[10]
        {
            return ( a[n] );
        }
    };

    A a;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = 10 * i + j;
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << a.a[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. That `operator[]` declaration makes my head hurt. If there's anybody else for whom it didn't click immediately, the way to declare a reference `a` to an array of 10 `int`s in C++ is with the slightly odd syntax `int (&a)[10]`. This example takes it one step further, and replaces `a` with `operator[](int n)` (i.e. the operator returns a reference to a int array of size 10). It's legal, it works, and it's certainly clever, but I'm not sure how I feel about it...